# How to create dynamically named testsets in Julia?

Tags: testing, julia

Using Julia's Test package, how can I create `@testset`s that reference a value at runtime?

E.g. I have

```
test_data = [
   (model="a",datapath="models/a.json"),
   (model="b",datapath="models/b.json"),
   ...
]
```

And I would like to do this:

```
@testset "models" begin
    for test in test_data
        @testset test.model begin
            
            # test range of values/functions here
        end
    end

end
```

But I get an error like this, which I assume is because I'm trying to define the testset name at runtime.

```
ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: LoadError: Unexpected argument test.model to @testset
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(::String) at .\error.jl:33
 [2] parse_testset_args(::Tuple{Expr}) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.5\Test\src\Test.jl:1244
 [3] testset_beginend(::Tuple{Expr,Expr}, ::Expr, ::LineNumberNode) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.5\Test\src\Test.jl:1087
 [4] @testset(::LineNumberNode, ::Module, ::Vararg{Any,N} where N) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.5\Test\src\Test.jl:1079
 [5] include(::String) at .\client.jl:457
 [6] top-level scope at C:\MyPackage\runtests.jl:7
 [7] include(::String) at .\client.jl:457
 [8] top-level scope at none:6
```

Because I'm running hundereds of tests in each inner `@testset` it would be really nice to have the results grouped when running the tests. Also, when I get an error it tends to be in *many* results and my terminal loses the history above where the error starts, so printing the model name before each set of tests doesn't work very nicely either.

Comment: Not an answer since it's not what you're trying to do, but I would suggest just writing loops over your test data. Why do you need to generate separate testsets for different items?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [interpolate](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/strings/#string-interpolation) the value of an expression in the test name using the standard `$` syntax:

```
julia> using Test

julia> i = 1
1

julia> @testset "Model $i" begin
           @test true
       end
Test Summary: | Pass  Total
Model 1       |    1      1
```

But in your case it is probably better to use the `@testset for ... end` syntax rather than the more common `@testset begin ... end` (see the [documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Test/#Test.@testset) for more detailed explanations):

```
julia> @testset "Model $i" for i in 1:2
           @test i == i
       end
Test Summary: | Pass  Total
Model 1       |    1      1
Test Summary: | Pass  Total
Model 2       |    1      1
```

---

In your specific use-case, it would look like:

```
julia> test_data = [
          (model="a",datapath="models/a.json"),
          (model="b",datapath="models/b.json"),
       ]
2-element Array{NamedTuple{(:model, :datapath),Tuple{String,String}},1}:
 (model = "a", datapath = "models/a.json")
 (model = "b", datapath = "models/b.json")

julia> @testset "Model $(test.model)" for test in test_data
           @test test.datapath == "models/$(test.model).json"
       end
Test Summary: | Pass  Total
Model a       |    1      1
Test Summary: | Pass  Total
Model b       |    1      1
```